# Setting default Content-Type for testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, content-type, pact

I'm working on some Pact Contract tests, using RestPactRunner, in the provider side, and I have the following problem. The endpoint return an "application/json" Content-type header when body is present like

```
ResponseEntity<>(anyValidBody, HttpStatus.OK)
```

But when no body is present, like this response

```
ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
```

an "Content-Type:text/plain" header is sent to the Client by default, even when `produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` is present in the method signature (and Contract Test fails because It's expecting an application/json header)

I was looking for a way to set the default content-type header in test level, but didn't found anything useful.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The response type for an HttpResponse is usually specified in the request mapping
eg:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

If its not specified spring would provide defaults in this case spring would provide application/json if any data is present and text/plain when there is not data.There is a method with following signature in which you can provide the headers for the response, you can set the content type using this method

```
public ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpStatus status)
```